# wordpress show total number of posts of a given taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

I want o fetch total number of posts of a custom taxonomy.

For eg: Custom taxonomy - recipe

In recipe I have tax terms as 
    `soups
    Deserts
    pastries`

Here is the [screenshot](http://puu.sh/a1Xae/892af3a21c.png)

and as you can see each term has associated posts for eg : **Deserts has 3 posts and pastries has 3 posts and soups has 2 posts**

So when i add code

```
$terms = get_terms($taxname,$taxoargs);
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            echo $term->name.$term->count;
}
```

It works perfect but what i need is It should show the total number of posts ([screenshot] here we can see total posts are 5[2](http://puu.sh/a1Xjb/6e670ba2c0.png)) I want to display this total number above my foreach loop.

So, in short, I want to count the total unique number of posts associated with any of the term.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### Amended Answer

Using a custom get post should fix it.

```
<?php
$args = array(
     'post_type' => 'recipe',
     'slug' => 'soups',
     'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$show_recipes= get_posts( $args );
echo $show_recipes->post_count;
?>
```

[Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Taxonomy_Parameters)

Comment: as i mentioned in question, i am already getting count for particlular term and i need total count before the loop

Comment: Is this a total count for every single term? The code above does the count before your loop.

Comment: what you have done is that shows term count i.e counted the custom taxonomy terms and what i want is count taxonomy term's posts

Comment: Ahh gotcha. Will amend answer in a second.